# UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL method does not work

Tags: iphone, html, string, uiwebview, local

I want to show a local html string content in a UIWebView using this :

```
[webView loadHTMLString:value baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

I dont know what's going wrong, but the web view remains white

thank's for help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"html"]];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];`